# How to make a mob spawner that can spawn mobs with custom drops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For a CTM map im making i would like a spawner that can spawn a **skeleton** that is: invisible, is wearing gold boots. which of course i found out how to do the problem is i would like it to drop xp bottles when it dies i tried doing lots of research and trying using [Custom mob spawner creators](http://www.minecraftupdates.com/summon-command) and [McStacker](http://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/) but none have the option to have the mobs drop custom items

**Questions**
- What argument do I need to add to a command to give the mobs their normal drops +bottles o enchanting
- How can  make the skeletons have the items above and drop 3-4 xp bottles

(Using 1.7.10)

Comment: I don't think this is "website" related. All of these "creators" just build commands to give you what you want in game. So therefore, if it isn't possible in game, it isn't possible on a website. ***This does not necessarily mean the same thing in reverse however***. It may be possible to create a command *in-game*, without the use of "creators" on the web.

Comment: That being said, this is most likely going to be closed as off-topic, as it is essentially a "recommendation" question. If you re-word it to perhaps be about finding the command to make the above possible, I think you'll have more of a chance at finding your answer.

Comment: @Ben i dont need the " 'creators' " to build me the command, i am looking for an example, website or hopefully some mcedit filter that i didnt find.

Comment: @Ben +1 on the off-topic, and no, it **is** possible for mobs to have custom drops of multiple items, and more than one of it. After all, what's `{count:[Qty]}` for anyway?

Comment: @kingbluesapphire That's exactly what makes this off-topic, since it's a website-recommendation question. If you change the focus of your question to the titular question (i.e. ask for the command) it is perfectly fine. Commands are quite complicated, and we have a lot of questions about finding a command to do something specific.

Comment: i edited it and fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Spawn mobs with a custom scoreboard score and summon the desired item on all entities with the custom scoreboard score that have a health of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MCStacker 2. It can be found [here](https://mcstacker.net/).

It has far more options when compared to the original including options to give mobs custom drops and link the command to a custom loot table.

It may also help you to join the [CTM community Discord](https://discord.gg/MGscgQd) for CTM related questions.